# Does facebook-java-api support app request

Tags: java, facebook, api

I'm currently trying to add the facebook apps request from our java server using facebook-java-api (3.0.5-snapshot)  (http://code.google.com/p/facebook-java-api/)

But it's seem that it's support everything except the apps request.

I was wondering if anybody manage to make it work event though this api seem to haven't change since 2009.

Am I missing something in the facebook-java-api that does or I have to use a new api or maybe simply call directly the rest request for that notification ?

Edit : While reading the [Facebook docs](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/) and this [question](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/5128798/facebook-api-get-the-request-object-for-a-request-id-logged-into-the-account-t), it seem that the short answer is you can't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We fixed it by using the http://restfb.com/ instead of the old and no longuer updated  facebook-java-api (3.0.5-snapshot) (http://code.google.com/p/facebook-java-api/)